# Sticky Rocker Light Switch -- Not stuck, just sticky -- fix or replace?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

My bathroom's light switch gets stuck in the on position very easily. I.e. I turn the light on and then I have to hit the switch 2-4 times to get it to turn off. It's a rocker switch.

It does turn off, but you really have to hit it hard. I've been doing some research on the internet, but I haven't really found questions about "sticky" light switches versus a light switch that is completely stuck in the on or off position. Do I absolutely have to replace it or is there a solution I can reasonably try myself? I rent my apartment so I would love it if I could just fix it myself instead of going through my landlord

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

That's not the kind of device that you'd attempt to repair. For one thing, you'd void the UL listing and assume liability for any resulting damage, injury, or death in doing so. For another, parts aren't available. For one more, they're far too inexpensive to waste any time on.

Buy a new switch. Turn of the breaker. Replace it in the same configuration following standard good wiring practice. Be happy.

Answer (score 2):

I've you're dead set on cleaning it, use rubbing alcohol, and thoroughly dry before thoroughly testing it in a fire-safe environment.  Several days later, you can then re-install it in the wall.  That's a terrible idea though.

You can pick up a high quality new switch for [less than a dollar after tax](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Single-Pole-Toggle-Switch-White-R52-01451-02W/100026991).

If you think you're going to gunk up the new one soon, you might get a [weatherproof cover](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Greenfield-Weatherproof-Electrical-Box-Lever-Switch-Cover-with-Single-Pole-Switch-Gray-KDL1P/202188640) instead for less than 5 bucks.  It comes with a new switch too apparently.  Easy DIY job!

[image: weatherproof cover]

Comment: Go the $8 route and buy a lighted flat panel switch. Will help in those sleep ridden nights hunting for a light switch after your hands have been gunked with butter from popcorn, then you can get back to Netflix and chill.

Comment: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-Illuminated-Switch-White-R72-05611-2WS/202035002